# groovy/xml - get the element with the bigger attribut value

Tags: xml, list, groovy

As an exemple I took this exemple to explain what I want

```
<records>
  <car name='HSV Maloo' make='Holden' year='2006'>
    <country>Australia</country>
    <record type='speed'>Production Pickup Truck with speed of 271kph</record>
  </car>
  <car name='P50' make='Peel' year='1962'>
    <country>Isle of Man</country>
    <record type='size'>Smallest Street-Legal Car at 99cm wide and 59 kg in weight</record>
  </car>
  <car name='Royale' make='Bugatti' year='1931'>
    <country>France</country>
    <record type='price'>Most Valuable Car at $15 million</record>
  </car>
</records>
```

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy's+XmlParser

I now how I can retreive a car entry with a specified year but I don't know how I can get the entry with the most recent year.

```
def records= new XmlParser().parse(xmlFile)

println records.car.find {it.'@name' == 'HSV Maloo' && it.'@year' == '2006'}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
println records.car.max { it.@'year'.toInteger() }
```